# ¿Qué diferencia existe entre los operadores && / & o || / |?

Tags: r

Quisiera saber cual es la diferencia entre `&&` y `&`, y entre `||` y `|` en R. De acuerdo  a [R definición de lenguaje](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Operators/%22R%20definici%C3%B3n%20de%20lenguaje%22) de la sección 3.14 Operadores. Según esta definición es que (`&`,`|`), están vectorizados mientras (`&&`,`||`) no. ¿Alguien podría explicarme las diferencias entre estos operadores lógicos y dar un ejemplo en que caso sería más apropiado usar cada uno?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Por empezar no está de más decir que `&&` o `&` es un `AND` lógico y `||` o `|` un `OR`. Una es una versión "larga" **no vectorizada** y la otra "corta", si es **vectorizada**. ¿Que significa esto?. veamos el caso del `AND` con un ejemplo:

```
> c(T,T) && c(T, F)
[1] TRUE

> c(T,T) && c(F, T)
[1] FALSE
```

En este la caso, usando la versión larga o **no vectorizada**, solo obtenemos un único valor, que es el que se corresponde con el `AND` del primer elemento de cada vector, el resto de los valores son ignorados, de ahí el hecho que se diga que es la versión **no vectorizada**.  `c(T, T) && c(T, F)` es equivalente a hacer `T && T` y `c(T,T) && c(F, T)` a `T & F`

La forma vectorizada aplica a todos los elementos de ambos vectores

```
> c(T,T) & c(T, F)
[1]  TRUE FALSE
> c(T,T) & c(F, T)
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

El resultado se corresponde con la operación lógica de cada uno de los elementos individuales de un vector con los del otro.

#### ¿Cuando usar una forma u otra?

Digamos que para la mayoría de los escenarios el `&` o `|` es la forma indicada, pero teniendo claro ahora, que la forma larga evalúa solamente el primer elemento de un vector, esto solo tiene sentido dentro de un bloque de control tradicional no vectorizado, por ejemplo un `if` o un `while/repeat`, dónde estas cláusulas de por sí, solo evalúan el primer elemento. Por ejemplo el siguiente `if` nos dará un Warning

```
> if (c(T,T) & c(T, T)) {print("Verdadero")}
[1] "Verdadero"
Warning message:
In if (c(T, T) & c(T, T)) { :
  la condición tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado
```

Para evitar este `Warning`, y obviamente solo si corresponde comparar únicamente el primer elemento, nos resulta apropiado, el usar el `&&` o el `||` ya que nos evitará el `Warning` y comparará de la forma que esperamos.