# ifelse con dos condiciones

Tags: array, r, if

Quiero crear una nueva variable a partir de dos dataframes, siempre y cuando se cumplan dos condiciones. El df 1 y el 2 tienen dos variables el común, pero sólo el df 1 contiene una variable que me interesaría unirle al df 2. He intentado usar la función vectorizada ifelse, pero no sé cuál es sintaxis para escribirle dos condiciones simultáneas.

He intentado sin éxito:

```
df2$Nuevavariable <- ifelse(df1$ID == df2$ID && 
                            df1$edad == df2$edad ,df1$sexo ,"NO")
```

He revisado también el post que aparece en [Nested ifelse statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012222/nested-ifelse-statement/18016872) y he seguido los ejemplos que pone ifelse anidados pero R me dice que tengo problemas con las comas.

Sé que otra opción que me quedaría sería hacer un merge, pero tengo tal número de variables que no me merece la pena generar un nuevo archivo con variables que no me interesan y luego ir quitándolas.

Comment: Para las preguntas que hagas, procura siempre incluir los mensajes de error que te muestra al probar tu código, copiando y pegando las trazas de error. :)

Answer (score 1):

El `ifelse()` únicamente podría servirte, si ambos `data.frame` tienen la misma cantidad de registros, los mismos `ID` y el mismo orden:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3), edad=c(20, 30, 45))
df2 <- cbind(df1, sexo = c("F", "M", "F"))
df1$NuevaVariable <- ifelse(df1$ID == df2$ID & df1$edad == df2$edad, as.character(df2$sexo) ,"NO") 
df1

  ID edad NuevaVariable
1  1   20             F
2  2   30             M
3  3   45             F
```

Como puedes ver `df2` es exactamente igual a `df1` solamente con una columna adicional, y muy importante, estamos usando el `and` lógico vectorizado y simple, es decir `&`, no uses en estos casos el `&&` ya que éste en particular,  solo verifica el primer elemento de cualquier vector. (más [info](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/165982/31764)). Ahora, si tan solo tuvieras distintas cantidades de elementos, o distintos `ID` o distinto orden, esta sentencia o no funcionaría o lo haría de forma inadecuada, por ejemplo, simplemente modificando el orden en el ejemplo:

```
df2 <- df2[c(2,3,1), ]

df1$NuevaVariable <- ifelse(df1$ID == df2$ID & df1$edad == df2$edad, as.character(df2$sexo) ,"NO") 
df1

  ID edad NuevaVariable
1  1   20            NO
2  2   30            NO
3  3   45            NO
```

Podemos verificar que ya no funciona de la forma esperada. Para lo que buscas, sin duda el `merge()`, es la forma adecuada de resolverlo:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3), edad=c(20, 30, 45))
df2 <- cbind(df1, sexo = c("F", "M", "F"))
df1 <- merge(df1, df2, by = c("ID","edad"), all.x=TRUE)
df1
  ID edad sexo
1  1   20    F
2  2   30    M
3  3   45    F
```

El `merge` hace un "matching" de las columnas indicadas por `by`, en este caso como los nombres de las columnas son los mismos, la función ya entiende esto, sino habría que definir las columnas de las dos tablas por separado con `by.x` y `by.y` el otro parámetro importante es `all.x=TRUE` con el que indicamos que queremos todas las filas de `df1` que coincidan o no con `df2`.

Si solo quieres la columna nueva, podrías hacer:

```
df1$NuevaVariable <- merge(df1, df2, by = c("ID","edad"), all.x=TRUE)[, "sexo"]
```

Comment: gracias por la aclaración con ifelse. Mis dos df tienen exactamente los mismos ID ordenados de forma descendente y aún así no me funciona, me pone "NO" siempre. He intentado también hacer el merge tal cual lo has puesto, pero el df final tiene más registros (3000 m´s) que los df de origen, que tienen exactamente el mismo número de registros de entrada (413000), lo cual no tiene mucho sentido. Alguna otra idea de como solventar el problema?

Comment: @Caro, si con el `merge` tal como te lo he indicado terminas con más filas de las que tiene el `df` de origen eso es un indicativo que los `data.frame` no son exactamente iguales, es probable que tengas algún `ID` repetido en `df2`, Para verificar si las filas son coincidentes en el orden, puedes hacer `all(df1$ID == df2$ID)` si te retorna `FALSE` quiere decir que no son exactamente iguales